# How to use prefect "mapped" to parallelize nested loops

Tags: prefect

I am trying to figure out how to parallelize nested loops with prefect, which require an inner fan out/in within the outer fan out/in.

If I use `map()` on the outer loop, then pass some of the results from outer loop calculations also using `map()` to inner loop in `unmapped()`, will this create an inner fan out? Then how do I do a "partial reduce" to use inner loop results in the outer loop?

A pointer or example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linking a conversation with OP about this on the Prefect Github for posterity: https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/2786

My tl;dr of that discussion for convenience: as of time of writing (Prefect version 0.12.0) dynamic pipelines with fan-out/fan-in is not supported by the existing `map` syntax. Today's `map` syntax only supports parallel pipelines of a constant cardinality. Instead, you would need to introduce a reduce step that reconfigures your outputs so they can be submitted to a new map.